# luxon convert local time to utc given a timezone

Tags: javascript, luxon

A data source has an ISO-8601 datetime field without an offset.

Example: `2019-07-09T18:45`

However, I know that the time in question is understood to be in the `America/Chicago` timezone.

How can I get a Luxon DateTime object of this time's equivalent in UTC?

I can do  `DateTime.fromISO('2019-07-09T18:45').plus({hours: 5})` ... but this will only be valid during half of the year (like now) when it is daylight savings time. Otherwise the offset would be `.plus({hours: 6})`

Does Luxon have a date-aware (and therefore DST-aware) method for converting from a specific zoned local time to UTC?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since you know the timezone of you input date, you can use the `zone` option when parsing it. As [`fromISO`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#static-method-fromISO) docs states:

> ```
> public static fromISO(text: string, opts: Object): DateTime
> ```
>
> `opts.zone`: use this zone if no offset is specified in the input string itself.

Then you can use [`toUTC`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-toUTC) to convert your DateTime to UTC:

> "Set" the DateTime's zone to UTC. Returns a newly-constructed DateTime.
>
> Equivalent to [setZone](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-setZone)('utc')

Here a live sample:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const d = DateTime.fromISO('2019-07-09T18:45', {zone: 'America/Chicago'});
console.log(d.toISO());
console.log(d.toUTC().toISO());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.16.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the following luxon function:

1. isInDST https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-get-isInDST

To check whether current time is based on DST or not!

2. toUTC : function to convert to UTC based time

https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-toUTC