# Date Unit test passed locally but failed in Gitlab CD/CI pipeline

Tags: unit-testing, date, gitlab, gitlab-ci, luxon

For date validation, I used [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) for my app. For each function I have made unit test. My unit test passed locally but when I deployed my code in gitlab, Most of my test failed. The expected result is so different than received. I don't understand what's the wrong. This my CD/CI pipeline images. [Image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkUbM.png), [image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlifO.png), [Image-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGQV6.png) and there are more. **Basically all my test failed**

### My all test passed in [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unit-testing-forked-eyrl5?file=/test/index.test.ts)

These are my all functions:

```js
import {
  DateTime
} from 'luxon'

export const DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT = 'd.M.yyyy'
export const SHORT_TIME_FORMAT = 'HH:mm'
export const ISO_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-MM-dd'
export const DATE_TIME_FORMAT = 'd.M.yyyy HH:mm'
export const DATE_MONTH_FORMAT = 'd.M'

export const WEEKDAYS = [
  'SUNDAY',
  'MONDAY',
  'TUESDAY',
  'WEDNESDAY',
  'THURSDAY',
  'FRIDAY',
  'SATURDAY',
]

export const dateToStrings = (date: string | number | Date): DateTime =>
  DateTime.fromISO(new Date(date).toISOString())

export const formatDateTime = (date: string | number | Date): string =>
  dateToStrings(date).toFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
export const formatDateMonthYear = (date: string | number | Date): string =>
  dateToStrings(date).toFormat(DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT)

export const formatTime = (date: string | number | Date): string =>
  dateToStrings(date).toFormat(SHORT_TIME_FORMAT)

export const NextDayFormatYearMonthDate = (date: string | number | Date): string =>
  dateToStrings(date).plus({
    days: 1
  }).toFormat(ISO_DATE_FORMAT)

export const PreviousDayFormatYearMonthDate = (date: string | number | Date): string =>
  dateToStrings(date).plus({
    days: -1
  }).toFormat(ISO_DATE_FORMAT)

export const dateDifference = (date: string | number | Date): number => {
  const diff = dateToStrings(date).diff(DateTime.now(), 'days').toObject()

  return Math.abs(Math.ceil(diff.days as number))
}

export const formatYearMonthDate = (date: Date | string | undefined): string => {
  if (!date) {
    //  if date is undefined, return empty string
    return ''
  } else {
    return dateToStrings(date).toFormat(ISO_DATE_FORMAT)
  }
}
export const weekNumber = (date: string | Date): number =>
  dateToStrings(date).startOf('week').weekNumber

export const nextWeek = (date: string | Date): string =>
  dateToStrings(date).startOf('week').plus({
    days: 7
  }).toFormat(ISO_DATE_FORMAT)

export const previousWeek = (date: string | Date): string =>
  dateToStrings(date).startOf('week').plus({
    days: -7
  }).toFormat(ISO_DATE_FORMAT)
export const firstDateOfWeek = (date: string | Date): string =>
  dateToStrings(date).startOf('week').toFormat(ISO_DATE_FORMAT)

export const lastDateOfWeek = (date: string | Date): string =>
  dateToStrings(date).startOf('week').plus({
    days: 6
  }).toFormat(ISO_DATE_FORMAT)

export const firstMondayOfTheWeekWithGMT = (date: Date): Date =>
  dateToStrings(date).startOf('week').toJSDate()

export const formatDateMonth = (date: string | Date): string =>
  dateToStrings(date).toFormat(DATE_MONTH_FORMAT)

export const shortDateString = (date: Date): string => {
  const shortForm = dateToStrings(date).setLocale('fi').toFormat('EEE')
  return shortForm.length > 1 ? `${shortForm.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${shortForm.slice(1)}` : ''
}

export const hasSameDay = (date1: Date, date2: Date): boolean =>
  dateToStrings(date1).hasSame(dateToStrings(date2), 'day')

export const isToday = (date: string | number | Date): boolean => {
  return dateToStrings(date).toISODate() === DateTime.local().toISODate()
}

export const compareDays = (
  date1: Date | string | number,
  date2: Date | string | number,
): number => {
  const compareWithDay = dateToStrings(date1).diff(dateToStrings(date2), ['days']).toObject()

  return Math.abs(Math.ceil(compareWithDay.days as number))
}
```

**This is my all tests**

```js
import {
  formatDateTime,
  formatDateMonthYear,
  formatTime,
  NextDayFormatYearMonthDate,
  PreviousDayFormatYearMonthDate,
  dateDifference,
  formatYearMonthDate,
  weekNumber,
  nextWeek,
  previousWeek,
  firstDateOfWeek,
  lastDateOfWeek,
  formatDateMonth,
  shortDateString,
  compareDays,
  DATE_MONTH_FORMAT,
  DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT,
  SHORT_TIME_FORMAT,
  ISO_DATE_FORMAT,
  DATE_TIME_FORMAT,
} from 'utils/date'
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'

const toDateString = 'Mon Feb 07 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)'
const toISOString = '2018-05-01T13:44:48.708709Z'
const today = new Date()
const tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
const yesterday = new Date(today.getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

describe('formatDateTime', () => {
  it('Should return format date time when date is string', () => {
    expect(formatDateTime('2022-02-11T06:44:57+00:00')).toBe('7.2.2022 00:00')
  })

  it('Should return format date time when date is toISOString', () => {
    expect(formatDateTime(toISOString)).toBe('1.5.2018 16:44')
  })
  it('Should return format date time when date is today', () => {
    expect(formatDateTime(today)).toBe(
      DateTime.fromISO(new Date().toISOString()).toFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT),
    )
  })
})

describe('formatDateMonthYear', () => {
  it('Should return format date when date is string', () => {
    expect(formatDateMonthYear(toDateString)).toBe('7.2.2022')
  })

  it('Should return format date when date is ISO String', () => {
    expect(formatDateMonthYear(toISOString)).toBe('1.5.2018')
  })

  it('Should return format date when date is today', () => {
    expect(formatDateMonthYear(today)).toBe(
      DateTime.fromISO(new Date().toISOString()).toFormat(DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT),
    )
  })
})

describe('formatTime', () => {
  it('Should return 00:00 when there is no time', () => {
    expect(formatTime(toDateString)).toBe('00:00')
  })

  it('Should return format time', () => {
    expect(formatTime(toISOString)).toBe('16:44')
  })

  it('Should return format time when date is today', () => {
    expect(formatTime(today)).toBe(
      DateTime.fromISO(new Date().toISOString()).toFormat(SHORT_TIME_FORMAT),
    )
  })
})

describe('NextDayFormatYearMonthDate ', () => {
  it('Should return next day format year when date is string', () => {
    expect(NextDayFormatYearMonthDate(toDateString)).toBe('2022-02-08')
  })

  it('Should return next day format year when date is ISOString', () => {
    expect(NextDayFormatYearMonthDate(toISOString)).toBe('2018-05-02')
  })
  it('Should return next day format year when date is today', () => {
    expect(NextDayFormatYearMonthDate(today)).toBe(
      DateTime.fromISO(new Date().toISOString()).plus({ days: 1 }).toFormat(ISO_DATE_FORMAT),
    )
  })
})

describe('PreviousDayFormatYearMonthDate', () => {
  it('Should return next day format year when date is string', () => {
    expect(PreviousDayFormatYearMonthDate(toDateString)).toBe('2022-02-06')
  })

  it('Should return next day format year when date is ISOString', () => {
    expect(PreviousDayFormatYearMonthDate(toISOString)).toBe('2018-04-30')
  })
  it('Should return next day format year when date is today', () => {
    expect(PreviousDayFormatYearMonthDate(today)).toBe(
      DateTime.fromISO(new Date().toISOString()).plus({ days: -1 }).toFormat(ISO_DATE_FORMAT),
    )
  })
})

describe('dateDifference', () => {
  it('Should return 0 when date is today', () => {
    expect(dateDifference(today)).toBe(0)
  })

  it('Should return 1 when date is not today', () => {
    expect(dateDifference(tomorrow)).toBe(1)
  })

  it('Should return 1 when date is not today', () => {
    expect(dateDifference(yesterday)).toBe(1)
  })
})

describe('formatYearMonthDate', () => {
  it('Should return format date when date is string', () => {
    expect(formatYearMonthDate(toDateString)).toBe('2022-02-07')
  })

  it('Should return format date when date is ISO String', () => {
    expect(formatYearMonthDate(toISOString)).toBe('2018-05-01')
  })

  it('Should return format date when date is today', () => {
    expect(formatYearMonthDate(today)).toBe(
      DateTime.fromISO(new Date().toISOString()).toFormat(ISO_DATE_FORMAT),
    )
  })

  it('Should return empty string when date is undefined', () => {
    expect(formatYearMonthDate(undefined)).toBe('')
  })
})

describe('weekNumber', () => {
  it('Should return week number when date is string', () => {
    expect(weekNumber(toDateString)).toBe(6)
  })

  it('Should return week number when date is ISO String', () => {
    expect(weekNumber(toISOString)).toBe(18)
  })

  it('Should return week number when date is today', () => {
    expect(weekNumber(today)).toBe(DateTime.fromISO(new Date().toISOString()).weekNumber)
  })
})

describe('nextWeek', () => {
  it('Should return next week date when date is string', () => {
    expect(nextWeek(toDateString)).toBe('2022-02-14')
  })

  it('Should return next week date when date is ISO String', () => {
    expect(nextWeek(toISOString)).toBe('2018-05-07')
  })
})

describe('previousWeek', () => {
  it('Should return previous week date when date is string', () => {
    expect(previousWeek(toDateString)).toBe('2022-01-31')
  })

  it('Should return previous week date when date is ISO String', () => {
    expect(previousWeek(toISOString)).toBe('2018-04-23')
  })
})

describe('firstDateOfWeek', () => {
  it('Should return first date of the week when date is string', () => {
    expect(firstDateOfWeek(toDateString)).toBe('2022-02-07')
  })

  it('Should return first date of the week when date is ISO String', () => {
    expect(firstDateOfWeek(toISOString)).toBe('2018-04-30')
  })
})

describe('lastDateOfWeek', () => {
  it('Should return first date of the week when date is string', () => {
    expect(lastDateOfWeek(toDateString)).toBe('2022-02-13')
  })

  it('Should return first date of the week when date is ISO String', () => {
    expect(lastDateOfWeek(toISOString)).toBe('2018-05-06')
  })
})

describe('formatDateMonth', () => {
  it('Should return format date month when date is string', () => {
    expect(formatDateMonth(toDateString)).toBe('7.2')
  })

  it('Should return format date month when date is ISO String', () => {
    expect(formatDateMonth(toISOString)).toBe('1.5')
  })

  it('Should return format date month when date is today', () => {
    expect(formatDateMonth(today)).toBe(
      DateTime.fromISO(new Date().toISOString()).toFormat(DATE_MONTH_FORMAT),
    )
  })
})

describe('shortDateString', () => {
  it('Should return first two letters Finnish weekdays when date is string', () => {
    expect(shortDateString(new Date(toDateString))).toBe('Ma')
  })

  it('Should return first two letters Finnish weekdays when date is ISO String', () => {
    expect(shortDateString(new Date(toISOString))).toBe('Ti')
  })
})

describe('compareDays', () => {
  it('Should return 0 if the dates are same', () => {
    expect(compareDays(new Date(toDateString), new Date(toDateString))).toBe(0)
  })

  it('Should return 0 if the dates are same', () => {
    expect(compareDays(new Date(toDateString), new Date(toISOString))).toBe(1378)
  })

  it('Should return 0 if the dates are string', () => {
    expect(compareDays(toDateString, toISOString)).toBe(1378)
  })
})
```

Comment: A likely source of variation would be the system's time zone. It probably works in your local timezone, but not in UTC or whatever your runner's timezone is. A datetime input that declares a timezone is probably converted by the library to the local time. Hence, the discrepancy of values when the local timezone is not the same as yours. You'll notice several examples are off by exactly two hours (expected: `00:00` actual: `22:00`) -- if you are in the timezone UTC+2, that would confirm the suspicion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference has to do with the timezone of your local computer and the timezone of the GitLab runner. The GitLab runners use UTC timezone.

Take this case for example:

```js
const toDateString = 'Mon Feb 07 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)'
// ...
describe('formatTime', () => {
  it('Should return 00:00 when there is no time', () => {
    expect(formatTime(toDateString)).toBe('00:00')
  })
```

In your unit test results:

```
Expected: "00:00"
Received: "22:00"
```

This would pass if your local timezone is UTC+2, but would fail if your timezone is UTC. `Mon Feb 07 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200` is `Sun Feb 06 2022 22:00:00` in UTC time.

From the [luxon docs](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html): (emphasis added)

> A DateTime comprises of:
>
> [...]
> A time zone. Each instance is considered in the context of a specific zone (**by default the local system's zone**).
> [...]

You'll probably want to normalize your tests to use a particular timezone. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56927110/5747944) for hints on how to change the timezone of the datetime objects.